# How to find two functions $f,g :\mathbb Z_2^n\to \mathbb Z_2^n$ such that $f(x)+f(y) $ and $g(x)+g(y)$ determines $\{x,y\}$ uniquely

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, soft-question, problem-solving, coding-theory

The following problem bothers me for some days, I could not clear out my mind to get a satisfying answer:

> How to find two functions $f,g :\mathbb Z_2^n\to \mathbb Z_2^n$ such that given $f(x)+f(y) $ and $g(x)+g(y)$ , we can find the two distinct elements $x,y\in \mathbb Z_2^n$ .

**My attempt :** ( I did not find the right approach to the problem yet)

The first thing I did is assuming that we can take $f=Id_{Z_2^n}$ (the identity function on $\mathbb Z_2^n$) , and the problem is equivalent to finding $g$ subject to $g(x+a)+g(x)=b$ having one or two solutions , but again I could not find any function that will do.

So I feel like I am missing something important here? do you have any ideas/ hints for me?

thank you.

**Edit**

First here is the **original problem** :

> It'is a game between two preople, Person $A$ choses two different elements $x,y$ in $\mathbb Z_2^n$ . The person $B$ does not know $x$ nor $y$ but he can ask $A$ one question of the form " what is the value of $f_1(x)+f_1(y), ...,f_k(x)+f_k(y)$?" for some functions $f_1, f_2, ... f_k$, and $A$ is constraint to answer this question in the form $a_1,..., a_k$. How many functions should $B$ use to find $\{x,y\}$?

My conjecture is that $2$ questions are enaugh, and that's what I try to prove without much success.

The conjecture is supported by the fact that, the number of values of $\{x,y\}$ is $2^{2n-1}-2^{n-1}$ and the pair $(f(x)+f(y),g(x)+g(y))$ can take up to $(2^n-1)^2$ values for $n\geq 3$

---

**Notation :**

- $\mathbb Z_2$ denotes  the quotient ring of the ring of integers modulo the ideal of even numbers, alternatively denoted by ${\displaystyle \mathbb {Z} /2\mathbb {Z} }$
- $\mathbb Z_2^n $ means the vector space of lenght $n$ over $\mathbb Z_2.$
- The functions $f$ and $g$ are not supposed to be linear or whatso ever, all maps are allowed

Comment: Interesting problem! I've noticed it's impossible for $n=1$.

Comment: for $n=1$ taking $f=g=Id$ will work, we will have $x+y=0$ or $x+y=1$ which always has either one solution $(0,0)$ or two solutions $(0,1),(1,0)$. I too have a feeling that it's impossible for larger $n$ but I can't prove it.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot we didn't need to know which way around they went.

Comment: yes we only need to know the set $\{x,y\}$ , even if we want we can't because the equations are symmetric on $x,y$

Comment: for every $x$, $f(x) + f(x) = 0$ and $g(x) + g(x) = 0$ so at least you can't differentiate between the cases where $x = y$.

Comment: @Michael There are $2^n$ output-values for $f(x) +f(y)$.

Comment: @Michael: yes $\mathbb Z_2^n = \mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2 \dots \times\mathbb Z_2 $ so the addition is mod-2 component-wise.

Comment: @themaker : well your comment on $f(x)+f(x)=0$ solves this if we assume the functions are added entrywise mod 2, but there is still a question if we allow $f(x) + f(y)$ to take values in $\{0,1,2\}^{n}$.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the case $x=y$, actually what I wanted is the case when they are different ( the case of equality does not matter to me), so l tried to formulate the problem in a mathematical way and I included the case $x=y$ but I was not carreful and I introduced the flow. The original question in the "orange block" does not contain the case $x=y$. Sorry for that . I modified the question.

Comment: The two formulations of the problem are not equivalent, you're describing two different problems here. Think about $n=1, (a, b)=(0, 1)$.

Comment: If you define an order $<$ on $\Bbb Z_2^n$ (say something like the lexicographical order), then your problem can be restated in terms of finding a certain *injective* function $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb Z_2^n\times\Bbb Z_2^n:x<y\}\to\Bbb Z_2^{2n}$, whereas your alternative formulation describes *bijections*.

Comment: @ThomasR, thank you for your comments, are the problems now equivalent and clear?  is there any formulation of the problem using order, I have a problem using that alongside the predefined operation $+$?

Comment: After posting your original problem, we now have three different problems. Note that trying $f$ and $g$ at the same time is different from trying $g$ *after* knowing $f(x)+f(y)$ for some $f$.

Comment: @ThomasR sorry for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a field structure on $\Bbb Z_2^n$, then pick $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x^3$.

If $x \neq y$ and you know $x+y = a ( \neq 0)$ and $x^3+y^3 = b$, 
then $b = (x+y)(x^2+xy+y^2) = a(a^2+xy)$, so that you know $axy = b+a^3$.

Then $x,y$ are the two roots of $a(T+x)(T+y) = aT^2+a^2T+(b+a^3)$.

This doesn't give you an easy way to actually find $x$ and $y$, but it is a proof that the map $(x,y) \mapsto (x+y,x^3+y^3)$ is $2$-to-$1$ away from the diagonal.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is an amazing idea, except that I do not know any operation $o$ such that $(Z_2^n,+,o)$ is a field $+$ is already defined? this is another important question

Comment: yes you want to keep your original $+$ and define a $\times$ that extends this into a field. It is always possible by picking an irreducible polynomial $P \in \Bbb Z_2[X]$ of degree $n$ and then looking at the quotient $\Bbb F_2[X]/(P)$. This is a finite field, and also a $\Bbb F_2$-vector space of dimension $n$.

Comment: Thank you for this original idea, this answers my question, I will try to find a method to compute $x,y$